# Efficient way to add new rules to a sublist within a nested list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I often build nested lists (as a way to keep data sets organised) with some form like:

```
 nestru = {"a" -> {"x" -> 5, "y" -> 7}, "b" -> {"x" -> 4, "y" -> 6}};
```

Here "a" and "b" are first order keys that associate a series of second order keys and values with the first order entity. If I want to add a new set of second order rules I can do something like:

```
 newru = {"z" -> "x"/"y", "xx" -> 2 "x"} /. nestru[[All, 2]]
```

> {{"z" -> 5/7, "xx" -> 10},
>
> {"z" -> 2/3, "xx" -> 8}}

Then I rebuild the whole data structure again:

```
MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {nestru[[All, 1]], 
 Flatten[#] & /@ Transpose@{nestru[[All, 2]], newru}}]
```

> {"a" -> {"x" -> 5, "y" -> 7, "z" -> 5/7, "xx" -> 10},
>
> "b" -> {"x" -> 4, "y" -> 6, "z" -> 2/3, "xx" -> 8}}

This feels like a clunky approach. Is there an 'cleaner'/more efficient way to add new sub-rules to a nested list of rules?

Comment: Instead of using nested lists, I would suggest to use nested `Association`s along with `AssociateTo`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher If I convert to `Association` how do I then use `AssociateTo` to add values to a 'sub'-`Association`? It's not clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show you another way. I'd go with associations and I'd make `newgru` longer but more robust (here "z", or "xx" could be replaced by rules from `nestgru` if you are not careful).

```
data = {"a" -> {"x" -> 5, "y" -> 7}, "b" -> {"x" -> 4, "y" -> 6}} // 
    GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations
```

> <|"a" -> <|"x" -> 5, "y" -> 7|>, "b" -> <|"x" -> 4, "y" -> 6|>|>

```
<|#, "z" -> #x/#y, "xx" -> 2 #x|> & /@ data
```

> <|"a" -> <|"x" -> 5, "y" -> 7, "z" -> 5/7, "xx" -> 10|>, 
>    "b" -> <|"x" -> 4, "y" -> 6, "z" -> 2/3, "xx" -> 8|>|>

Comment: It's about time for me to read more about associations... The only problem I see is how to turn it back into a list of rules? If I use `Normal` only the top level changes to a `List`. Again It feels like I have to rebuild the data structure if I want utilise lists of rules.

Comment: @geordie don't go back! But if you really need to: `data /. Association -> Normal@*Association`

Comment: Moving forward, I'll try not to go back (!) but I currently work with large ecosystem built on lists of rules. It may be that I can use most of this will work with `Association`'ed structures but I'll need to do some testing. For the moment (until I can brush up) 'old school' seems like the safest way to proceed...

Comment: @geordie Just a remark: `Association`s are essentially hash tables, so -- in contrast to lists -- operations like insert and delete do not need a full copy of the data structure. Thus `Association` should not only be much more convenient but also much more efficient. However, they come with a certain extra memory cost. You might also find `Dataset` interesting.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, about your insert/delete remark, does it hold for `Association`s not assigned to a symbol? I have always thought that if an expression isn't assigned to a symbol, the Kernel will make a copy on any modification of this expression to provide immutability...